# Custom Implementation of indexOf for LeetCode problem

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement the following code from LeetCode:

*Return the index of the first occurrence of needle in haystack, or -1 if needle is not part of haystack.

**Clarification:**

What should we return when needle is an empty string? This is a great question to ask during an interview.
For the purpose of this problem, we will return 0 when needle is an empty string. This is consistent to C's strstr() and Java's indexOf().

**Constraints:**
0 <= haystack.length, needle.length <= 5 * 104
haystack and needle consist of only lower-case English characters.*

I have the following C# solution for the problem:

```
public static int StrStr(string haystack, string needle)
    {
        if (needle.Length == 0) return 0;
        if (haystack.Length == 0) return -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < haystack.Length; i++)
        {
            if(haystack[i] == needle[0]){
                int match = 0;
                int index = i;
                for (int j = 0; j < needle.Length && index < haystack.Length; j++, index++)
                {
                    if (needle[j] == haystack[index])
                        match++;
                    else
                        break;
                }
                if (match == needle.Length) return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

It's passing all the test cases except the one where a really large string is passed as an input to the function as a result of which the program is exceeding the time limit. Can anyone tell me how can I make this code run faster?

Comment: That really large string, is it passed as haystack, or as needle?

Comment: This seems better suited to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: [Examples of search algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm#Examples_of_search_algorithms)

Comment: @Martheen the test case that failed was passing haystack as really long string

Comment: @Llama I was not aware about Code Review. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You can have a look at this [blog post about ripgrep](https://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/#literal-optimizations) which is a tool that does text search.
The blog talks about your actual problem and the state of the art of making this as fast as possible and might get you started in the right direction.